# Fileupload control looses value on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have webform having following structure.
First update panel have fileupload control.
Second update panel have dropdownlist along with one panel which contain textbox.Onselected index change of dropdownlist,panel get visible(textbox get visible).But when I browse the file using fileupload and after that I choose to select a value from dropdownlist, fileupload control looses the value.
How to handle that?After 2 update panel one calendar control and one button control.I want to save and read the file from button control event

```
// Update panel 1 start
   // fileupload control
// update panel 1 end 


// Update panel 2 start
   // dropdownlist with selected index change event
   // On selected index change textbox get visible
// update panel 2 end 

// Calender control
// Generate button
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain value in Fileupload control in asp.net,C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026087/maintain-value-in-fileupload-control-in-asp-net-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second update panel's postback refreshes the content in first update panel as well.

You should set **UpdateMode="Conditional"** in your UpdatePanel to prevent it.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mschray/2013/06/05/update-panel-update-mode-always-vs-conditional-or-why-is-my-ajax-control-losing-focus/

Comment: Thanks Kiran for ur help.It work fine with me when I used  UpdateMode="Conditional" in my first update panel which contain fileupload control.Bydefault updatemode is 'always',means anywhere inside page postback happen,it refresh other update panel,in order to avoid that use ,conditional mode.But when I clicked on button control,unable to get value of fileupload control.

Comment: 1. You should remove the UpdatePanel 1 which contains the fileupload control (if it contains only fileupload control, then there is no purpose using it inside update panel)
2. Use UpdateMode="Conditioal" in second update panel

Comment: Thanks Kiran for ur reply.I forgot to tell that first updatepanel contain checkbox ,textbox along with fileupload control.If I select checkbox,fileupload control become visible and textbox become non visible.For that I added update panel.